# Detect scrolling in Subclass of UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, subclass

Good morning,

I've creates a Subclass of UIScrollView and I now want to know when the user is scrolling in my subclass. For that I implemented it like the following:

ImageScroller.h

```
@interface UIImageScroller : UIScrollView <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
```

ImageScroller.m (within the @implementation)

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    NSLog(@"did scroll");
}
```

The problem is, that the method scrollViewDidScroll doesn't seem to get fired.
Is there any possibility to get it to work?

I also tried to set the delegate to it self, but it doesn't work.

```
 - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
        self.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
        [self setDelegate:self];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I added a ScrollView to my XIB-File and set the Class if it to my ImageScroller. Also I've set the Fileowner and I'm using the UIScrollViewDelegate in the .h-File of the ViewController as well as implementing the Method scrollViewDidScroll in the .m-file.

When I set the delegate of my ImageScroller in the code of the .m-file from the XIB like 
    [imageScroller setDelegate:imageScroller]
the scrollViewDidScroll is fired in my ImageScroller-Subclass, but the one in my ViewController isn't fired, but I need both.

Any solutions for that?

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can try setting self.delegate = self; to receive events.

Comment: I tried it like this, but it doesn't work for some reason.
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {

        self.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
        [self setDelegate:self];
    }
    return self;
}

Comment: I added a ScrollView to my XIB-File and set the Class to my ImageScroller. I also set the Fileowner and I'm using the UIScrollViewDelegate in the .h-File of the ViewController as well as implementing the Method scrollViewDidScroll in the .m-file. Is that maybe a problem?

Comment: I didn't get it the first time :) So your delegate method is working but only in your delegate (the scroll view)? Wel that's the way things are supposed to be, because there is only one delegate. I think you might set the delegate to your controller then and make it somenhing like this

`- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    //do controller stuff here
    [self.view scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)self.view];
}
`
But I'm not still not sure if that's the problem.

Answer (score 15):

I ran into the same problem creating a subclass of the UIScrollView but solved it this way.  As mentioned above, you can set yourself (subclass instance) as the delegate however this is what I did.

In the sub class I overrode the following methods

```
//Override this to detect when the user is scrolling, this is also triggered during view
//layout.  Here you can check your deceleration rate and determine when the scrolling has
//grinded to a halt.
-(void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset

//Override this to detect when the view has been resized (just a handy override)
-(void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame;
```

As far as the other `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods, the View Controller should be responsible for handling those in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is looking for a Swift answer, it's as simple as this:

```
override var contentOffset: CGPoint {
    didSet {
        if contentOffset != oldValue {
            //same as scrollViewDidScroll
        }
    }
}
```